# add header for a client in getAsync (in a using block )

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, using, using-directives

Trying to add a header property to the client variable here. New to C#/ window forms.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = client.GetAsync(page).Result)
using (var content = response.Content) {
           response = content.readAsStringAsync().Result();
       }
```

I want to add a header to the above code.

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("myHeader", "value");
```

Not sure of where to put it. Tried adding in using(var client = new HttpClient() { client.addheader('header', 'value') }. But that seems to make client out of scope in next lines of code.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling asynchronous versions of those methods if you're just going to block on the results.  If you want synchronous behavior, just call the synchronous versions of those operations to begin with.

Comment: [I have a blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/) on how to use `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Servy is there no way I could add a header when calling async method of http client ?

Comment: @RkRBairi Sure you can, I never said otherwise.  I just said that if you want to do the work synchronously, call the synchronous methods.  If you want to do the work asynchronously then don't synchronously block on the returned tasks immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you layout the code properly you will see where to scope the variables.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("myHeader", "value");
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page)) {        
       var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments try not to block (.Result) on async code.

Also `HttpClient` should be long living. constantly initializing and disposing them can have adverse effects on performance.